# ValueError when trying to create a following relationship in Django

Tags: python, django

I have looked through the similar SOverflow questions and no answer helped.
I am trying to create a follower/following relationship when a button is pressed, passing the info through Javascript...

```
function follow(user) {
    fetch(`/profile/${user.id}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            followed: user.id
        })
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(() => load_profile(user.id))
}
```

...then I receive it and try to save it or update it...

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def view_profile(request, user_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        followed = data.get("followed", "")
        follower = request.user.id
        obj, created = UserFollowing.objects.get_or_create(user_id=followed, following_user_id=follower, following=True)
        if not created:
            obj(following=False)
            obj.save()
        return JsonResponse({"message": "(Un)Followed successfully."}, status=201)
```

... and this is the model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "user": self.username,
            "following": self.following.count(),
            "followers": self.followers.count(),
        }

class UserFollowing(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="following")
    following_user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="followers")
    following = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=True)
```

ERROR:  `ValueError: Cannot assign "3": "UserFollowing.user_id" must be a "User" instance.`
I have tried to pass different values such as the username, the object itself, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
followed = data.get("followed", "")
```

If your body message (data) does not contain followed keyword than empty string will be assigned to `followed` variable otherwise a number.

Both cases would make you trouble later at this line, where `followed` has to be a user object and  can't be an empty string or a number.

```
obj, created = UserFollowing.objects.get_or_create(user_id=followed, following_user_id=follower, following=True)
```

You will also get the same error at the following line where you assign a number to the `follower` variable which, according to your model, has to be a user object as well.

```
follower = request.user.id
```

Possible solution to that:

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def view_profile(request, user_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        if "followed" in data: 
          followed = data["followed"]
          try:
            user = User.objects.get(id=followed)
          except:
            # user does not exist
        follower = request.user
        obj, created = UserFollowing.objects.get_or_create(user_id=user, following_user_id=follower, following=True)
        if not created:
            obj(following=False)
            obj.save()
        return JsonResponse({"message": "(Un)Followed successfully."}, status=201)
```

Comment: Thank you, Patrik! How would the model look like if i could be able to create an object with the id's?